# Nativescript 7 vue app crashes for some users on Android splash screen

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-vue

We have received reports from around 5 users that the app has started crashing while still displaying the splash screen. We don't have device and API information for all of them, but the most recent specified a "fully updated" Galaxy Note 10. I also have a crash report from an internal track on the play store as well for a Pixel 5 running Android 11. We haven't been able to replicate the crash on any devices so far.

The tail end of the crash report:

```
05-28 10:20:42.628: I/BufferEulogizer(2152): Not eulogizing buffers; they are 450617 hours old
05-28 10:20:42.789: D/dumpstate(21089): Duration of 'APP SERVICES PLATFORM': 0.62s
05-28 10:20:42.817: D/SSRestartDetector(3461): Ramdump list uri is null.
05-28 10:20:42.837: I/CallDataProvider(4155): query database
05-28 10:20:42.837: I/CallDataProvider(4155): Checking to delete any unwanted records..
05-28 10:20:42.838: I/CallDataProvider(4155): Date changed or does not exist..
05-28 10:20:42.846: I/CallDataProvider(4155): Creating database:SQLiteDatabase: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.apps.scone/databases/call_data_logs.db
05-28 10:20:42.849: I/CallDataProvider(4155): case all items android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@23700b6
05-28 10:20:42.849: I/CallDataProvider(4155): query database
05-28 10:20:42.850: I/CallDataProvider(4155): case all items android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@666f1b7
05-28 10:20:42.850: I/CallDataProvider(4155): query database
05-28 10:20:42.850: I/CallDataProvider(4155): case all items android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@204dd24
05-28 10:20:43.000: I/.gms.persisten(11634): Compiler allocated 4121KB to compile void diu.c(java.io.PrintWriter)
05-28 10:20:43.298: D/BluetoothAdapter(11634): isLeEnabled(): ON
05-28 10:20:43.299: D/BluetoothAdapter(11634): isLeEnabled(): ON
05-28 10:20:43.302: I/NearbyDiscovery(11634): FastPairScanner2: isAlive? bleEnabled:true, btEnabled:true, bleScanAvailable:false [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
05-28 10:20:43.689: I/CHRE(886): @ 552.781: [ImuCal] [NanoSensorCal:GYRO_RPS] Offset | Temperature [C]: 0.001124, 0.000151, 0.001114 | 31.64
05-28 10:20:43.689: I/CHRE(886): @ 552.781: [ImuCal] [NanoSensorCal:GYRO_RPS] Temp Sensitivity: 0.000003, -0.000025, -0.000031
05-28 10:20:43.689: I/CHRE(886): @ 552.781: [ImuCal] [NanoSensorCal:GYRO_RPS] Temp Intercept: 0.000995, 0.000961, 0.002102
05-28 10:20:44.227: D/VSC(886): @ 553.319: [WO] isFlat() nearest_rotation: 1, flat_angle: 40
05-28 10:20:44.227: D/VSC(886): @ 553.319: [WO] orientation angle 90, orientation 1
05-28 10:20:44.285: I/CarrierServices(5723): [498] dfq.d: RCS Configuration storage in Bugle is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getProvisioningConfigurationForGivenSim()
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944): Decoder.dump():1123 Failed to get dump info
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] qep.d()' on a null object reference
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at com.google.android.keyboard.client.delight5.Decoder.dump(PG:69)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at juc.dump(PG:11)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at dwq.a(PG:317)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at dwq.dump(PG:313)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDumpService(ActivityThread.java:4269)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:237)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1971)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
05-28 10:20:44.516: W/Delight5Decoder(2944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
05-28 10:20:44.576: I/AndroidIME(2944): PopupSearchCandidateViewControllerExtension.dump():85 PopupSearchCandidateViewControllerExtension, popupSearchCandidateViewController:fus@d6e8f6
05-28 10:20:44.577: I/OnDeviceRecognizerModule(2944): OnDeviceRecognizerModule.dump():38 dump()
05-28 10:20:44.579: I/OnDevicePackDownloadModule(2944): OnDevicePackDownloadModule.dump():111 dump()
05-28 10:20:44.580: I/FallbackOnDeviceRecognizerModule(2944): FallbackOnDeviceRecognizerModule.dump():34 dump()
05-28 10:20:44.724: I/putmethod.lati(2944): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 85244(4518KB) AllocSpace objects, 40(1520KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 9538KB/18MB, paused 77us total 115.975ms
05-28 10:20:44.831: I/QCNEJ/NativeHalConnector(2565): -> SND dump CND
05-28 10:20:44.862: D/dumpstate(21089): Duration of 'APP SERVICES NON-PLATFORM': 2.07s
05-28 10:20:44.898: W/DynamiteModule(20800): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
05-28 10:20:44.912: I/DynamiteModule(20800): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
05-28 10:20:44.912: I/DynamiteModule(20800): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
05-28 10:20:44.976: I/DynamiteLoaderV2Impl(20800): [70] Googlecertificates
05-28 10:20:45.286: E/DebugContentProvider(5809): Could not get an instance of the instrumentation.
05-28 10:20:45.342: W/Bugle(21170): AssistantIntegrationStartupTask: Error getting assistant availability.
05-28 10:20:45.342: W/Bugle(21170): atcq: Timed out (timeout delayed by 30 ms after scheduled time): asyq@ad20a06[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[atcm@12048c7[status=PENDING]], function=[afdl@1d5cef4]]]
05-28 10:20:45.383: D/QCNEJ/WlanStaInfoRelay(2565): Received action: android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
05-28 10:20:45.384: I/QCNEJ/NativeHalConnector(2565): -> SND notifyWlanStaStatusChanged([WlanStaInfo]: wifiSwitchState = 1 rssi = -56 ssid = wl-mm-mi16-1-5 bssid = 38:17:c3:13:61:50 dnsInfo = 10.10.100.100;10.10.100.101;0.0.0.0;0.0.0.0; freqBand = _5GHz countryCode = [RatInfo]: networkType = 1 subType = 101 networkState = CONNECTED netHdl = 432902426637 ipAddrV4 = 10.12.189.173 ipAddrV6 =  ifNameV4 = wlan0 ifNameV6 =  slotIdx = 0 isAndroidValidated = true) timeStamp = 2021-05-28 10:20:45.383
05-28 10:20:45.404: E/PhoneInterfaceManager(2583): [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPrivilegeStatus: Invalid subId
05-28 10:20:45.408: I/CarrierServices(5723): [427] csd.onConnectivityChange: FiST: Wifi connectivity status true
05-28 10:20:45.414: I/CarrierServices(5723): [457] czz.c: (PEv2-SM): DisabledState: event Connectivity event [null]
05-28 10:20:45.419: E/PhoneInterfaceManager(2583): [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPrivilegeStatus: Invalid subId
05-28 10:20:45.419: I/CarrierServices(5723): [461] dfq.d: RCS Configuration storage in Bugle is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getProvisioningConfigurationForGivenSim()
05-28 10:20:45.421: I/CarrierServices(5723): [427] csw.d: Connected state: [1], networkType: [WIFI]
05-28 10:20:45.481: I/Forking(21170): Starting analysis.
05-28 10:20:45.481: I/Misthreading(21170): Starting analysis.
05-28 10:20:45.564: I/DynamiteModule(21170): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:17 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:48
05-28 10:20:45.564: I/DynamiteModule(21170): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 48
05-28 10:20:45.564: V/DynamiteModule(21170): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
05-28 10:20:45.613: I/BugleRcsEngine(21170): [1438] hhl.a: Provisioning task in Bugle is disabled by P/H flag
05-28 10:20:45.623: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Scheduling periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK 21600
05-28 10:20:45.624: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Scheduling periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.MAINTENANCE.PERIODIC.GCM.TASK 86400
05-28 10:20:45.624: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Scheduling periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.CELLULAR.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK 21600
05-28 10:20:45.625: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Scheduling periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.WIFI.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK 3600
05-28 10:20:45.625: I/BugleMDD(21170): MddBackgroundStartupTask: Scheduled MDD periodic tasks.
05-28 10:20:45.632: I/BugleNetwork(21170): Startup: registering tachyon.
05-28 10:20:45.633: I/DynamiteLoaderV2Impl(21170): [71] MeasurementDynamite.integ
05-28 10:20:45.651: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Successfully updated periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.MAINTENANCE.PERIODIC.GCM.TASK 86400
05-28 10:20:45.652: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Successfully updated periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.CELLULAR.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK 21600
05-28 10:20:45.666: I/BugleNetwork(21170): Startup: skip phone registration because of no sim.
05-28 10:20:45.671: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Successfully updated periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK 21600
05-28 10:20:45.681: D/MDD WorkManagerTaskScheduler(21170): Successfully updated periodic tasks for MDD lib MDD.WIFI.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK 3600
05-28 10:20:45.737: I/Bugle(21170): VerifiedSmsStartupTask: Checking if Verified SMS tasks should be enqueued. feature supported: true, feature enabled: true, eligible / has registered key: false, C11N: true
05-28 10:20:45.737: I/Bugle(21170): VerifiedSmsStartupTask: Not enqueuing VSMS periodic task, VSMS is disabled or not supported.
05-28 10:20:45.738: I/Bugle(21170): VerifiedSmsStartupTask: Calling C11N to get phone numbers...
05-28 10:20:45.745: I/Bugle(21170): VerifiedSmsRegistrationHelper: The device doesn't have a new IMSI not registered with VSMS.
05-28 10:20:45.745: I/Bugle(21170): VerifiedSmsStartupTask: C11N registration didn't update with any new data.
05-28 10:20:45.389: D/ConnectivityService(1575): NetReassign [no changes]
05-28 10:20:45.781: D/ConnectivityService(1575): requestNetwork for uid/pid:10205/21170 NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ]
05-28 10:20:45.781: D/ConnectivityService(1575): NetReassign [100 : null → 100]
05-28 10:20:45.781: D/WIFI_AWARE_FACTORY(1575): got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ] with score 60 and providerId 5
05-28 10:20:45.781: D/Ethernet(1575): got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ] with score 60 and providerId 5
05-28 10:20:45.782: D/PhoneSwitcherNetworkRequstListener(2583): got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ] with score 60 and providerId 5
05-28 10:20:45.782: D/UntrustedWifiNetworkFactory(1575): got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ] with score 60 and providerId 5
05-28 10:20:45.782: D/WifiNetworkFactory(1575): got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ] with score 60 and providerId 5
05-28 10:20:45.790: D/MddListenableWorkerFactory(21170): createWorker for class: com.google.android.libraries.mdi.download.workmanager.workers.PeriodicWorker
05-28 10:20:45.792: D/MddPeriodicWorker(21170): PeriodicWorker: startWork
05-28 10:20:45.865: D/PowerUI(2152): can't show warning due to - plugged: true status unknown: false
05-28 10:20:45.866: D/DeviceStatisticsService(2517): chargerType=2 batteryLevel=100 totalBatteryCapacity=4081700
05-28 10:20:45.867: D/DeviceInfoHidlClient(2517): isPowerInfoNeverSent()=true
05-28 10:20:45.867: D/DeviceInfoHidlClient(2517): getPowerInfoSupportStatus()=-1
05-28 10:20:45.873: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:45.877: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dqe.a: Received Provisioning Event: [Bugle information (100)]
05-28 10:20:45.884: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dqe.a: JibeService is running, passing event to provisioning engine.
05-28 10:20:45.894: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] ddi.a: Handling Provisioning Event: [Bugle information (100)]
05-28 10:20:45.898: W/Icing(15133): Record file /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/query-record-log.tmp not found, ignoring
05-28 10:20:45.899: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] ddr.a: RcsAvailabilityManager: Calculating Rcs Availability
05-28 10:20:45.911: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] ddr.a: Bugle ContentProvider is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getBugleHasRequiredPermission()
05-28 10:20:45.916: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] ddr.a: Bugle has minimum required RCS permissions: true
05-28 10:20:45.921: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.d: RCS Configuration storage in Bugle is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getProvisioningConfigurationForGivenSim()
05-28 10:20:45.933: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.a: Bugle ContentProvider is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getBugleEnabledRcsFromPreference()
05-28 10:20:45.940: I/gle.android.gm(15133): Compiler allocated 4343KB to compile void achv.a(android.content.Context, java.io.PrintWriter, java.lang.String[], abeb)
05-28 10:20:45.944: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.a: Rcs is enabled from user settings: true
05-28 10:20:45.948: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.b: Bugle ContentProvider is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.isBugleDefaultSmsApp()
05-28 10:20:45.954: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:45.954: I/chatty(21170): uid=10205(com.google.android.apps.messaging) BG Thread #3 identical 1 line
05-28 10:20:45.954: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:45.957: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.b: Bugle is default SMS app: true
05-28 10:20:45.958: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:45.962: I/chatty(21170): uid=10205(com.google.android.apps.messaging) BG Thread #3 identical 9 lines
05-28 10:20:45.962: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:45.968: W/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dgz.a: No config URL. RCS will be disabled!
05-28 10:20:45.969: I/gle.android.gm(15133): Compiler allocated 4557KB to compile void achv.a(android.content.Context, java.io.PrintWriter, java.lang.String[], abeb)
05-28 10:20:45.986: I/FA(21170): App measurement initialized, version: 39058
05-28 10:20:45.986: I/FA(21170): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
05-28 10:20:45.987: I/FA(21170): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
05-28 10:20:45.987: I/FA(21170):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging
05-28 10:20:45.992: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.d: RCS Configuration storage in Bugle is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getProvisioningConfigurationForGivenSim()
05-28 10:20:46.003: I/chatty(5723): uid=10182(com.google.android.ims) AsyncTask #12 identical 1 line
05-28 10:20:46.025: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dfq.d: RCS Configuration storage in Bugle is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getProvisioningConfigurationForGivenSim()
05-28 10:20:46.040: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] dzm.b: Checking if using CarrierServices.apk is possible. Enabled: true, isAtLeastM: true, runningInsideBugle: false
05-28 10:20:46.050: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] bnm.onCsLibPhenotypeUpdated: BindingManager: binding and reset P/H Flag stay same
05-28 10:20:46.056: I/CarrierServices(5723): [497] ddr.a: RcsAvailabilityManager: Rcs Availability still DISABLED_SIM_ABSENT (RCS is disabled due to SIM absent)
05-28 10:20:46.233: D/VSC(886): @ 555.325: [WO] isFlat() nearest_rotation: 1, flat_angle: 40
05-28 10:20:46.233: D/VSC(886): @ 555.325: [WO] orientation angle 90, orientation 1
05-28 10:20:46.476: I/GMS_MM_Logger(15133): Memory Metric Logging not allowed. Stopping.
05-28 10:20:46.480: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups webref-model-local-index
05-28 10:20:46.495: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smart_actions_grammars
05-28 10:20:46.587: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smart_actions_ml_models
05-28 10:20:46.627: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030000 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f03000d is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f03000e is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f03000f is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030017 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030018 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030019 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030022 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030025 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030026 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.628: E/earchbox:searc(11847): Resource 7f030029 is a complex map type.
05-28 10:20:46.630: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups text_classifier
05-28 10:20:46.697: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smart_actions_emotive_models
05-28 10:20:46.847: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smarts_expressive_content_scoped_v1
05-28 10:20:46.850: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups scripted_reply
05-28 10:20:46.855: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups multitask_experiment
05-28 10:20:46.857: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups spam_verdict_enforcement_policy_config
05-28 10:20:46.859: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups calendar_appointment_grammar
05-28 10:20:46.918: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:46.928: I/chatty(21170): uid=10205(com.google.android.apps.messaging) BG Thread #2 identical 13 lines
05-28 10:20:46.928: E/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Failed to add file group 
05-28 10:20:46.997: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups webref-model-local-index
05-28 10:20:47.002: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smart_actions_grammars
05-28 10:20:47.007: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smart_actions_ml_models
05-28 10:20:47.013: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups text_classifier
05-28 10:20:47.021: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smart_actions_emotive_models
05-28 10:20:47.085: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups smarts_expressive_content_scoped_v1
05-28 10:20:47.087: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups scripted_reply
05-28 10:20:47.097: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups multitask_experiment
05-28 10:20:47.098: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups spam_verdict_enforcement_policy_config
05-28 10:20:47.100: D/PhFileGroupPop(21170): Added file groups calendar_appointment_grammar
05-28 10:20:47.105: I/WM-WorkerWrapper(21170): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=43421715-bf78-4ad6-8557-c00995a5d60f, tags={ MDD.WIFI.CHARGING.PERIODIC.TASK, com.google.android.libraries.mdi.download.workmanager.workers.PeriodicWorker } ]
05-28 10:20:47.109: D/ConnectivityService(1575): releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=100, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10205 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10205 RequestorPackageName: com.google.android.apps.messaging] ] (release request)
05-28 10:20:47.317: D/PowerUI(2152): can't show warning due to - plugged: true status unknown: false
05-28 10:20:47.318: D/DeviceStatisticsService(2517): chargerType=2 batteryLevel=100 totalBatteryCapacity=4081700
05-28 10:20:47.318: D/DeviceInfoHidlClient(2517): isPowerInfoNeverSent()=true
05-28 10:20:47.318: D/DeviceInfoHidlClient(2517): getPowerInfoSupportStatus()=-1
05-28 10:20:47.656: D/rlsservice(895): MonitorDisplayStatus client num 1, display status 1, sensor status 1
05-28 10:20:48.257: D/VSC(886): @ 557.349: [WO] isFlat() nearest_rotation: 1, flat_angle: 40
05-28 10:20:48.257: D/VSC(886): @ 557.349: [WO] orientation angle 90, orientation 1
05-28 10:20:48.398: D/ConnectivityService(1575): NetReassign [no changes]
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847): Write failure
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847): java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:540)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:398)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushBytesLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:354)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:377)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:322)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:640)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:1004)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:56)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.debug.a.g.a(SourceFile:36)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.debug.a.g.a(SourceFile:127)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.contentprovider.initializer.c.dump(SourceFile:6)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDumpProvider(ActivityThread.java:4301)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:237)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2013)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.Linux.writeBytes(Native Method)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.Linux.write(Linux.java:293)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.write(ForwardingOs.java:240)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:418)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.write(ForwardingOs.java:240)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:535)
05-28 10:20:48.483: W/FastPrintWriter(11847):   ... 19 more
05-28 10:20:48.544: I/CarrierServices(5723): [498] dfq.d: RCS Configuration storage in Bugle is disabled by p/h flag, using ProvisioningEngineStateCacheUtil.getProvisioningConfigurationForGivenSim()
05-28 10:20:48.648: D/dumpstate(21089): Duration of 'APP PROVIDERS NON-PLATFORM': 3.38s
05-28 10:20:48.687: D/dumpstate(21089): Not adding dir /linkerconfig because it's not a zipped bugreport
05-28 10:20:48.687: D/dumpstate(21089): Not dumping incident report because it's not a zipped bugreport
05-28 10:20:48.687: D/dumpstate(21089): Duration of 'DUMPSTATE': 61.26s
05-28 10:20:48.744: I/dumpstate(21089): Vibrate: 'cmd vibrator vibrate -f 75 dumpstate'
05-28 10:20:48.752: E/VibratorService(1575): Ignoring incoming vibration as process with uid= 2000 is background, attrs= VibrationAttributes: Usage=TOUCH Flags=1
05-28 10:20:48.753: I/cmd(23863): oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
05-28 10:20:48.880: I/dumpstate(21089): Vibrate: 'cmd vibrator vibrate -f 75 dumpstate'
05-28 10:20:49.023: I/dumpstate(21089): Vibrate: 'cmd vibrator vibrate -f 75 dumpstate'
05-28 10:20:49.036: I/cmd(23869): oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
05-28 10:20:49.164: D/dumpstate(21089): Final progress: 8810/8904 (estimated 5000)
05-28 10:20:49.164: I/dumpstate(21089): Saving stats (total=8810, runs=1, average=8810) on 
05-28 10:20:49.164: I/dumpstate(21089): done (id 1)
05-28 10:20:49.341: E/WifiHAL(918): handleResponse: OTHER_RX_MULTICAST_CNT not found
05-28 10:20:49.603: W/LastMileLogger(1575): Failed to read event trace: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/trace
05-28 10:20:49.855: W/ip(23913): type=1400 audit(0.0:684): avc: denied { search } for name="net" dev="dm-9" ino=37 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:net_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-28 10:20:49.959: E/WifiHAL(918): handleResponse: OTHER_RX_MULTICAST_CNT not found
05-28 10:20:50.213: W/LastMileLogger(1575): Failed to read event trace: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/trace
05-28 10:20:50.257: D/VSC(886): @ 559.349: [WO] isFlat() nearest_rotation: 1, flat_angle: 40
05-28 10:20:50.257: D/VSC(886): @ 559.349: [WO] orientation angle 90, orientation 1
```

The app dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "^7.3.0",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/iqkeyboardmanager": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^2.0.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-calendar": "^3.0.0",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^7.0.1",
    "nativescript-directions": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-email": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-fancyalert": "^3.0.9",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-gif": "^5.0.0",
    "nativescript-phone": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-sentry": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-socketio": "^3.3.1",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.8.4",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.4.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "husky": "^3.0.8",
    "lint-staged": "^9.4.2",
    "nativescript": "^6.1.2",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "2.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^6.0.4",
    "vue-loader": "15.9.3"
  }
```

I am not familiar with Android crash reports, and I couldn't spot anything that identified the issue when reading over this. I do see a number of errors, some of which are related to the application package. Is there information here that clarifies the cause of the crashes?

I just noticed that the nativescript version in the dependencies here is 6.1.2, but the global version is 7.

Comment: I also found this information in the play console: "Abort message: 'Pointer tag for 0x6def9ae310 was truncated.'" That lead me to this page: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/tagged-pointers. Am I reading this correctly that a library in use here is not yet compatible and I should modify AndroidManifest.xml to add <application android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false">?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact the Android 11 tagged pointers support conflicting with the nativescript-sentry plugin. It looks like the next release (after 2.0.1) of nativescript-sentry has the Sentry updates that should include the correct fix for this, but for now the workaround in https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/tagged-pointers resolves the issue.